# Using dataset in C#

Tags: c#, dataset

This is something I do in VB.net all the time and i'm trying to replicate it in c#. Basically I have a dataset connected to sqlserver and i'm trying to add a new row. I have the following, but rMainPID seems to be null.

```
   private components.db.PIDSDB.MainPIDDataTable dtMainPID;
   private components.db.PIDSDBTableAdapters.MainPIDTableAdapter taMainPID = new components.db.PIDSDBTableAdapters.MainPIDTableAdapter();
```

Then Main:

```
  protected void doSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 ClientID = Convert.ToInt32(txtCompanyClientID.Text);
            String ChannelLead = Request.Form["ChannelLead"];
            // String ChannelSalesPerson = Request.Form["ChannelSalesPerson"];
            String ChannelSalesPerson = "Test";
            String DropDeadDate = Request.Form["DropDeadDate"];
            String MCSalesLead = Request.Form["MCSalesLead"];
            Int32 ProjectTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ProjectTypeID"]);
            Int32 ProjectStatusID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ProjectStatusID"]);
            String ClientBriefing = Request.Form["ClientBriefing"];
            String ProjectRequirements = txtProjectRequirements.Text;

            components.db.PIDSDB.MainPIDRow rMainPID = default(components.db.PIDSDB.MainPIDRow);
            rMainPID = dtMainPID.NewMainPIDRow();
            rMainPID.ClientID = (ClientID);
            rMainPID.ChannelLead = (ChannelLead);
            rMainPID.ChannelSalesPerson = (ChannelSalesPerson);
            rMainPID.DropDeadDate = (DropDeadDate);
            rMainPID.MCSalesLead = (MCSalesLead);
            rMainPID.ProjectTypeID = (ProjectTypeID);
            rMainPID.ProjectStatusID = (ProjectStatusID);
            rMainPID.ClientBriefing = (ClientBriefing);
            rMainPID.ProjectRequirements = (ProjectRequirements);

            dtMainPID.AddMainPIDRow(rMainPID);
            taMainPID.Update(dtMainPID);

        }
```

[image]

Comment: dtMainPID is null and therefore you can't use it to return a new instance of MainPIDRow

Comment: Please check the object `dtMainPID` is nothing or not

Comment: Well yes, I get that, however I don't know how to fix it - it shouldnt be empty so putting a check around it being nothing or not wont make it error no, but it wont do the update.

Comment: @TomBeech why shouldn't it be empty? when do you assign something to `dtMainPID` ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `dtMainPID` is `null`, presumably because you never assign anything to it. We would *expect* `rMainPID` to be `null`, because that is the variable we are trying to populate at the time - but: you need to assign a value to `dtMainPID` at some point *before* trying to use it.

Incidentally:

- the `= default(components.db.PIDSDB.MainPIDRow);` does nothing useful; you might as well declare and init on the same line:

  ```
  var rMainPID = dtMainPID.NewMainPIDRow();
  ```
- `DataTable` : just... please consider investigating non-`DataTable` approaches to data access at some point; *think of the kittens*